# Как достать по ключу в json python?

Tags: python, база-данных, json

Есть вот такой кусочек json бд.

```
{
      "features": [
        {
          "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
              37.529659,
              55.824708
            ],
            "type": "Point"
          },
          "properties": {
            "DatasetId": 1796,
            "VersionNumber": 2,
            "ReleaseNumber": 4,
            "RowId": null,
            "Attributes": {
              "global_id": 637377165,
              "ID": "000021938",
              "Name": "Бильярдный клуб Golden Kugel",
              "IsNetObject": "нет",
              "OperatingCompany": null,
              "TypeObject": "бар",
              "AdmArea": "Северный административный округ",
              "District": "район Коптево",
              "Address": "город Москва, Большая Академическая улица, дом 24, корпус 2",
              "PublicPhone": [
                {
                  "PublicPhone": "(495) 450-72-80"
                }
              ],
              "SeatsCount": 43,
              "SocialPrivileges": "нет",
              "Longitude_WGS84": "37.5296590000000000",
              "Latitude_WGS84": "55.8247080000000000"
            }
          },
          "type": "Feature"
        }
    }
```

Как мне на python достать coordinates. Парсирую вот так:

```
data = json.load(open("c:\db.json", "r"))
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
import json



data = json.load(open("c:\db.json", "r"))
coord = data['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']
print(coord)
```